# Is 0 recurring allowed in repeating decimals?

Tags: number-theory

After a question in [Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41136/writing-numbers-in-repeating-decimal) and not being able to find anything which answers this:

Is zero recurring allowed in repeating/recurring decimals?

So can I write something like: $$5 = 5.\overline{0}$$ or even:

$$4.\overline{9} = 5.\overline{0}$$

If it isn't, then would this mean that $0$ is the only rational number which cannot be written as a repeating decimal?

Comment: I don't see what would make zero special....

Comment: Yes, it is true that $4.\overline{9} = 5.\overline{0}$, and choosing between the two decimal representations of the same number comes up in certain proofs.

Comment: Note that the digit $0$ must be allowed to recur, or there will be lots of numbers (like $1/11=0.\overline{09}$) which have no repeating decimal expansion. The only way to get $0$ to be the *only* rational number which cannot be so written is to ban $0$ from recurring by itself, but allow it to recur with other numbers, which seems even more like special pleading...

Comment: I'm guessing the intended answer was 0 can not be written as repeating digits but, like everyone else here, I believe that to be dead wrong.  In fact.  *most* texts I've seen when defining and describing decimal representations of all reals prefer to make the blanket statement all real numbers are infinite sums and the so called terminating ones are merely those with infinite zeros, or to be more accurate finite non-zeros.  It would seem to be twisting ourselves into pretzels to make an exception for zero for utterly no reason I can see.

Comment: @Micah but in 1/11 it is not the zero nor the 0 that recurs.  It's the "09".  But again I see no logic that that .499999 is repeating but that .50000 is not.  Hurkyl.  The only thing that makes zero special would mean that we don't need to explicitly state it.  But that doesn't mean we *can't* express it.  Indeed we *have* to be able to express.  It's imposible to say $5 = 5 \ne 5 + 0/10 + 0/100 + .....$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Furthermore, it's convenient to assume that *all* places in a decimal are filled, so any terminating decimal notation implicitly means to fill the unmarked positions with zeros.

That is, by $1.5$, we really mean $\bar{0}1.5\bar{0}$.

Comment: Note that zero really is special if you use "repeating" leading digits.

Comment: If the leading digits need to be filled this does make an exception to leading digits in that there is at most finite nonzero leading terms and there is always a first nonzero leading term (or none at all).  Actually, I wouldn't say it is convenient at all to say the leading places are filled.

Comment: @fleablood: Each to their own, I suppose, but I neither see why your comment suggests it's inconvenient, nor off the top of my head know of any mathematics that isn't more complicated by requiring there to be only finitely many places to the left of the decimal point. e.g. it's simply simpler to say the real number represented by a decimal is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n 10^n$.

Comment: @fleablood: Also, being left finite isn't actually a requirement: there's 10's complement notation, 10-adic numbers, and I've even seen real-world computer computations that found it most efficient to represent rational numbers via _left_ repeating numerals (albeit binary ones).

Comment: My understanding is that 10-adic numbers do not represent integers nor real numbers, do they.  The standard meaning of decimal notion means the number represents the value $\sum_{i\in \mathbb Z}b_i*10^i$  if such has an infinite non-zero $b_i$ for positive $i$ the sum is not a finite value.  At least that is my understanding.  10-adic numbers, if I understand right, mean something quite different.